# Async publish on a JMS topic using webmethods

Tags: asynchronous, webmethods

How do I do an async publish for a JMS topic hosted on a webmethods broker? I am looking for something similar to what Active MQ provides, but using webmethods instead:

http://activemq.apache.org/async-sends.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "a JMS topic hosted on a webmethods broker", but you can publish any webMethods document anywhere in your flow with the pub.publish:publish service.  You can subscribe to any published document by adding a trigger on that document type, along with the flow service that should be called when the document is received.

A bit different than ActiveMQ, but pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It has a sample C# project:

http://techcommunity.softwareag.com/ecosystem/communities/codesamples/webmethods/messaging/SAMPLE-20120523120201999.html